# Overwrite dask dataframe with sklearn scaler

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, dask

I have the following dask dataframe:

[image]

For which I want to apply the sklearn scaler, E.G to the column LotArea:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(df[['LotArea']])
```

That returns a numpy array as:

```
array([[ 0.82160041],
       [ 1.59216945],
       [ 1.46485804],
       [-0.11648362],
       [-1.10613315],
       [ 0.34906243],
       [-0.23942507],
       [-0.11648362],
       [ 0.40033659],
       [-0.11706628],
       [-0.85762828],
       [-2.07480689]])
```

But I can not update the dataframe as:

```
df[column] = (scaler.fit_transform(df[[column]]))
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray
```

I try it casting it to a dask array, but got the same result:

```
df['LotArea'] = da.from_array(scaler.fit_transform(df[[column]]))

TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.array.core.Array
```

How can I use the scaler to update the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to "How do I add a column to a Dask DataFrame".

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

In [23]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)

In [24]: b = da.from_array(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), chunks=2)

In [25]: ddf['B'] = dd.from_dask_array(b, index=ddf.index)

In [26]: ddf.head()
/Users/taugspurger/sandbox/dask/dask/dataframe/core.py:5724: UserWarning: Insufficient elements for `head`. 5 elements requested, only
2 elements available. Try passing larger `npartitions` to `head`.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(n, len(r)))
Out[26]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
```

This could probably be made easier within Dask. See https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5118.